# How can i import ImageMagick libraries in Android?

Tags: android, import

i am using ImageMagick in my project, I get it from [guthub](https://github.com/lilac/Android-ImageMagick).  After editing some code from there, when I compile this I am getting this error:

```
12-06 11:26:08.976: E/AndroidRuntime(1800): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
```

on this line of code:

```
final MagickImage img = new MagickImage(new ImageInfo("/sdcard/image.jpeg"));
```

And this error:

```
12-06 11:26:08.976: E/AndroidRuntime(1800): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: init
```

on this line of code:

```
System.loadLibrary("android-magick");
```

This is the logcat:

```
12-06 14:29:40.566: E/AndroidRuntime(4095): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-06 14:29:40.566: E/AndroidRuntime(4095): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
12-06 14:29:40.566: E/AndroidRuntime(4095):at com.colors.photo.magic.AndroidMagickActivity.onCreate(AndroidMagickActivity.java:33)
12-06 14:29:40.566: E/AndroidRuntime(4095):at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
12-06 14:29:40.566: E/AndroidRuntime(4095):at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
12-06 14:29:40.566: E/AndroidRuntime(4095):at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
12-06 14:29:40.566: E/AndroidRuntime(4095):at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
12-06 14:29:40.566: E/AndroidRuntime(4095):at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
12-06 14:29:40.566: E/AndroidRuntime(4095):at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-06 14:29:40.566: E/AndroidRuntime(4095):at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-06 14:29:40.566: E/AndroidRuntime(4095):at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
12-06 14:29:40.566: E/AndroidRuntime(4095):at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-06 14:29:40.566: E/AndroidRuntime(4095):at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
12-06 14:29:40.566: E/AndroidRuntime(4095):at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
12-06 14:29:40.566: E/AndroidRuntime(4095):at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
12-06 14:29:40.566: E/AndroidRuntime(4095):at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-06 14:29:40.566: E/AndroidRuntime(4095): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:    init
12-06 14:29:40.566: E/AndroidRuntime(4095):at com.colors.photo.magic.Magick.init(Native Method)
12-06 14:29:40.566: E/AndroidRuntime(4095):at com.colors.photo.magic.Magick.    <clinit>(Magick.java:37)
12-06 14:29:40.566: E/AndroidRuntime(4095):     ... 14 more
```

Comment: Please show more from your logs

Comment: @brainbowler Again, FIX all the errors, not just one typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that native library was not found. Check your build environment.  Of course you will need library compiled for proper CPU

Comment: careful reading of android tools documentation would surely help you. if you are using eclipse,  there must be setting somewhere to add native library